# Text in pdf output not recognized

Tags: fonts, pdf, windows, copy-paste

I am writing my first document with Latex, so please be patient ;-) I've searched through forums again and again but was unable to find a solution.
I am working with Texmaker and when compiling my Latex document, everything works fine, I even can print the document as pdf, but then it seems that that pdf recognizes everything as one image because you cannot select any texts or sentences within the document and its size is rather big.
Did I forget to include some package or is the problem connected to the pdf creator?

One further detail: There is no automatic hyphenation in the whole document, but I thought with `\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}` it happens automatically.

The code for my document looks like the following:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\EUR}

\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\usepackage{scrpage2}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadings
\clearscrplain

\ohead{\headmark}
\cfoot{\pagemark}
\setheadsepline{1pt}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\newcommand\fnurl[2]{%
\href{#2}{#1}\footnote{\url{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\bibliography{citavi001}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you open the document with Adobe Reader, what it says about used fonts? Are they Type 1 or 3?

Comment: There do not appear any fonts...

Comment: How do you compile your document? latex+dvipdfmx? pdflatex? Can you provide a simple file (with unnecessary peckages removed, and with few text lines) showing the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I tried to shorten my code, but since I am not sure about the roots of the problems I wanted to show as most packages used as possible, and check for the possibility that I should not use some at the some time. For compiling my document I use: PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX (x2) + show pdf

Comment: @C.Schupp: I tried your example and compiled with `pdflatex`, the text is selectable regularly and pasteable into an ordinary text file without problems (TL 2015, compiling with Linux, using Adobe Reader)

Comment: What is your distribution?

Comment: Thank you Christian Hupfer for trying! I am really getting hopeless to find the reason why it is not working with me. @Bernard: Sorry, but what do you mean by distribution?

Comment: MiKTeX, or TeX Live?

Comment: My distribution is MikTeX