# Prepare pdfs as good as possible for making them accessible with Adobe Acrobat Pro

Tags: pdf, acrobat, accessibility

I am struggling to create accessible pdfs directly with LaTeX in the first place. Therefore, I am trying to retrofit some accessibility options using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC. However it seems, that not even text is recognized in a LaTeX-compiled pdf. This seems very strange to me. Is there anything that I have to keep in mind when I compile the document to prepare it for making it accessible with Adobe Acrobat Pro?

[image]

Comment: [Possibly related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313357/). You may also find the [`copy-paste`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copy-paste?tab=Votes) tag on this website of interest, which the aforementioned question is a part of. For more general accessibility matters, see e.g. [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6306/) question, or the [`accessibility`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility?tab=Votes) or [`pdfcomment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdfcomment?tab=Votes) tags.

Comment: Note that DVI format stores each character and its (x,y) location separately, so you definitely want pdflatex.

Comment: Interim result: I compressed the compiled PDF with PDF24 and afterward I was able to apply the Action Tool for Making Accessibly. It already looks much better. .. Let's see where this gets me.

Comment: Don't bother looking at `accessibility`. It's badly broken (I'm the maintainer) and I'm not sure if its fixable.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to create an accessible PDF with LaTeX today is to create a PDF/A-Nb, N being 1 to 3. The sole thing LaTeX fails is tagging. The rest like colour management and adding tags it can do. Use `hyperxmp` to add all the metadata you need. See [this minimal example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/540669/50129) as a starting point.

In order to check accessibility the free [PAC3](https://www.access-for-all.ch/ch/pdf-werkstatt/pdf-accessibility-checker-pac.html) is imo better than Acrobat Pro.

Once you have metadata and colour management Acrobat Pro is quite good in generating tags. Nevertheless usually you need some manual adjustments (also in Acrobat Pro) to achieve *meaningful* tagging. The real test is to read your document with «reflow» (Ctrl+4) enabled.